# How to generate a histogram with the list below?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to generate a histogram with the list below?

```
[[0, 0, 0, 19, 7], [0, 0, 0, 21, 7], [0, 0, 0, 21, 7], [0, 0, 0, 29, 0]]
```

**Explaining the list:** [0, 0, 0, 19, 7]

- First value = repetition average between `0-20`
- Second value = repetition average between `20-40`
- Third value = repetition average between `40-60`
- Fourth value = average repetition between `60-80`
- Fifth value = repetition average between `80-100`

These sublists within the list can grow exponentially, I would like each sub-list to have a distance between each other, to better interpret the graph

What I have achieved so far:

```
result = [[[0, 0, 0, 19, 7], [0, 0, 0, 21, 7], [0, 0, 0, 21, 7], [0, 0, 0, 29, 0]]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
for i in range(len(result)):
    data = np.array(result[i])
    x=np.arange(len(data)) + i*6
    # draw means
    ax.bar(x-0.2, data[:,0], color='blue', width=0.4)
    ax.bar(x+0.2, data[:,1], color='green', width=0.4)
    ax.bar(x-0.2, data[:,2], color='yellow', width=0.4)
    ax.bar(x+0.2, data[:,3], color='orange', width=0.4)
    ax.bar(x+0.2, data[:,4], color='red', width=0.4)
# separation line
ax.axvline(4.75)
# turn off xticks
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.legend(labels=['0-20', '20-40', '40-60', '60-80', '80-100'])
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.legendHandles[0].set_color('blue')
leg.legendHandles[1].set_color('green')
leg.legendHandles[2].set_color('yellow')
leg.legendHandles[3].set_color('orange')
leg.legendHandles[4].set_color('red')
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.ylabel('Consume')
plt.xlabel('Percent')
plt.show()
```

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to draw the described plot. Note that normally matplotlib only sets one legend entry for a complete bar graph. To have an entry for individual bars, a label needs to be set to each of them explicitly. In the code below such a label is added to each bar in the first set.

(Note that I left out one set of square parenthesis for `result` as in the original post it is a 3D list. If such a 3D list would be necessary, you could write the loop as `for i, data in enumerate(result[0])`).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

result = [[0, 0, 0, 19, 7], [0, 0, 0, 21, 7], [0, 0, 0, 21, 7], [0, 0, 0, 29, 0]]
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']
labels = ['0-20', '20-40', '40-60', '60-80', '80-100']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
for i, data in enumerate(result):
    x = np.arange(len(data)) + i*6
    bars = ax.bar(x, data, color=colors, width=0.4)
    if i == 0:
        for bar, label in zip(bars, labels):
            bar.set_label(label)
    if i < len(result) - 1:
        # separation line after each part, but not after the last
        ax.axvline(4.75 + i*6, color='black', linestyle=':')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.legend()
ax.set_title("Histogram")
ax.set_ylabel('Consume')
ax.set_xlabel('Percent')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]